# PHP really strange incorrect behaviour with DateTime only on production server

Tags: php, datetime

Simply as:

```php
    $end   = new \DateTime();
    $start = clone $end;

    // Remove 30 days from today and set midnight
    $start->sub(new \DateInterval('P30D'));
    $start->setTime(0, 0);

    var_dump(new \DateInterval('P30D'));
    var_dump($start, $end); die();
```

Output (nicely formatted):

```
object(DateInterval)#1516 (8)
{ ["y"]=> int(0)
  ["m"]=> int(0)
  ["d"]=> int(30)
  ["h"]=> int(0)
  ["i"]=> int(0)
  ["s"]=> int(0)
  ["invert"]=> int(0)
  ["days"]=> int(0) }

object(DateTime)#1523 (3)
{ ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-06-19 00:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
  ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Europe/Rome"
}

object(DateTime)#4682 (3)
{ ["date"]=> string(19) "2012-08-18 02:42:23"
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
  ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Europe/Rome"
}
```

An error of 1 month... any clue?

**EDIT**:  correct behavior only when using:

```
$start->modify('-30 days');
```

Commenting out the `DateInterval` line.

```
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 19 2012 01:35:33)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2009, by mOo

Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 18:09:18
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your environment, but remember that 1 month !== 30 days

Comment: @Alfo of course i do. Error of "1 month" is a generic phrase. It's a huge anyway.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `var_dump` of the `DateInterval` and see what period it holds? This way you can see if it's that object that doesn't work properly, or if it's the `sub()` function.

Comment: @Diego dit it, updated question. It works, so problem is sub().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of DateTime bugs have been [fixed since 5.3.2](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php)
I tested your code on 5.3.16 and it works fine, no duplicate subtraction.

Answer (score -1):

Whats with the backslashes? As Far, as I can see everything looks right.

Comment: Backslash is because the namespace (programming with Symfony 2 framework). Maybe this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49059 can help, but i'm not substracting twice.. what do you think about that bug?